# Here Maps - What HTTP status code does it return when API Quota was exceeded?

Tags: api, here-api, quota, here-maps-rest, heremaps

I am developing an app which uses the distance calculation of HERE maps API...

I am preparing for the case when the API doesn't return what my app expects (correct response including distance infos). So I want to be prepared for the case the `API Request Quota was exceeded`...

**What HTTP `status code` does it return when API Quota was exceeded?**

Does it return a 200 with some JSON which explains that and error occurred because of quota?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you exceed the Location Services 250,000 Transactions or Data Hub 2.5GB Data transfer or 5GB Database storage included for free in the Freemium plan, you'll receive an email telling you to add payment details to your account.
You'll have some "wiggle room" above your limits to help ensure your access is not unintentionally shut down. However, it's possible to exceed the threshold, including "wiggle room", which would result in account deactivation, even before we can notify you.

for detail please check the FAQ section with question

> "12. What happens if I exceed limits on my Freemium plan?"

https://developer.here.com/faqs#payment-and-subscription

Comment: Not going to downvote but you don't answer to the question. Email is a thing, but what http code your api response for exceeded quota ? Imo the answer is 429 (used by google in that use case), or 402 (paiement required to upgrade plan), some will say 409 is fine, or 400 i nothing appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

You should also get a 429 error from the API, with a message "Limit Exceeded".